# Perl program structure for parsing

Tags: linux, perl, parsing, logging, universal

I've got question about program architecture.
Say you've got 100 different log files with different formats and you need to parse and put that info into an SQL database. 
My view of it is like:

1. use general config file like:

   ```
   program1->name1("apache",/var/log/apache.log) (modulename,path to logfile1)
   program2->name2("exim",/var/log/exim.log) (modulename,path to logfile2)

   ....

   sqldb->configuration
   ```
2. use something like a module (1 file per program) type1.module (regexp, logstructure(somevariables), sql(tables and functions))
3. fork or thread processes (don't know what is better on Linux now) for different programs.

So question is, is my view of this correct? I should use one module per program (web/MTA/iptablat)
or there is some better way? I think some regexps would be the same, like date/time/ip/url. What to do with that? Or what have I missed?

---

example: mta exim4 mainlog

> **2011-04-28 13:16:24 1QFOGm-0005nQ-Ig**
>   <= exim@mydomain.org.ua** **H=localhost
>   (exim.mydomain.org.ua)**
>   [127.0.0.1]:51127 I=[127.0.0.1]:465
>   P=esmtpsa
>   X=TLS1.0:DHE_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA1:32
>   CV=no A=plain_server:spam S=763
>   id=**1303985784.4db93e788cb5c**@mydomain.org.ua T=**"test"** from
>   <**exim@exim.mydomain.org.ua**> for
>   **test@domain.ua**

everything that is **bold** is already parsed and will be putted into sqldb.incoming table. now im having structure in perl to hold every parsed variable like `$exim->{timstamp} or $exim->{host}->{ip}`

my program will do something like `tail -f /file`  and parse it line by line

Flexability: let say i want to add supprot to apache server (just timestamp userip and file downloaded). all i need to know what logfile to parse, what regexp shoud be and what sql structure should be. So im planning to have this like a module. just fork or thread main process with parameters(logfile,filetype). Maybe further i would add some options what not to parse (maybe some log level is low and you just dont see mutch there)

Comment: What kind of data do you want to have in the database, after all? do you expect the list of applications to grow (e.g. postfix)? What are your expectations regarding flexibility?

Comment: ive updated my question. is it more clear now or have i add something more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

1. Create a config file that is formatted like this: appname:logpath:logformatname
2. Create a collection of Perl class that inherit from a base parser class.
3. Write a script which loads the config file and then loops over its contents, passing each iteration to its appropriate handler object.

If you want an example of steps 1 and 2, we have one [on our project](http://openmelody.org). See MT::FileMgr and MT::FileMgr::* [here](https://github.com/openmelody/melody/tree/master/lib/MT).

Comment: i've forgotten about classes. This sounds good. Do you think sql driver should be in that class too?

Answer (score 0):

The log-monitoring tool [wots](http://www.e-dynamics.be/index.php?section=programs&lang=en) could do a lot of the heavy lifting for you here. It runs as a daemon, watching as many log files as you could want, running any combination of perl regexes over them and executing something when matches are found.

I would be inclined to modify `wots` itself (which its licence freely allows) to support a database write method - have a look at its existing `handle_*` methods.

Most of the hard work has already been done for you, and you can tackle the interesting bits.

Answer (score 0):

I think File::Tail is a nice fit.
You can make an array of File::Tail objects and poll them with select like this:

```
   while (1) {
       ($nfound,$timeleft,@pending)=
         File::Tail::select(undef,undef,undef,$timeout,@files);
       unless ($nfound) {
              # timeout - do something else here, if you need to
       } else {
           foreach (@pending) {
                # here you can handle log messages depending on filename  
                print $_->{"input"}." (".localtime(time).") ".$_->read;
       }
```

(from perl File::Tail doc)